# Edit tab available to anonymous user on some but not all pages?

Tags: 6, users, entities

On a Drupal 6 site that I've inherited, there is a custom content type for staff profiles.  Editing should be limited to two user roles "content creator" and "careers."  This has worked fine for the past 2+ years, but a few weeks ago we noticed that some, but not all, of the individual staff page/nodes are editable buy anonymous users (anyone!).

I've looked at the permissions for this content type as well as for all our user roles-- nothing indicates that this should be possible at all.

The only way I've been able to "fix" this is by recreating the nodes 1-by-1 and deleting the "broken" ones.

I'm particularly curious as to why this only affects some nodes-- I have so far been unable to detect any sort of pattern that connects them.

Any ideas where I should be looking to diagnose this?

Comment: have you installed/enabled a contributed module before you notice this issue?

Comment: Are there any node access modules installed? If so, I'd try rebuilding access permissions.

Comment: @Aboodred1 - Haven't installed any modules in the past few months, and the problem reared its ugly head a couple of weeks ago...

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong - excellent suggestion, but no joy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally found out what was happening.  Drupal was configured so that when an authorized user account was deleted, the owner for all their content was changed to Anonymous.  Modified the setup so that the owner of all "orphaned" pages is set to Admin.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. How/where did you make that change to owner of all 'orphaned' pages is set to Admin?